# add Onclick on adapter for each item to open new different activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have Adapter in my project and few fragments where I populate fragments with celebrity names and date of birth as it is given in below image
[image]

I will like to call a different url to launch for each item

For First Item

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com")));
```

For Second Item

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com")));

and so on

Below is my Adapter Class

```html
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Model> mDataset;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView nameText;
        public TextView phoneText;
        public NetworkImageView image;
        @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            nameText = v.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            phoneText = v.findViewById(R.id.phone_text);
            image = v.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
            image.setDefaultImageResId(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Position: "+getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(List<Model> myDataset, Context mCOntext) {
        Log.d("TEST",myDataset.get(0).getName());
        mDataset = myDataset;
        mImageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(mCOntext).getImageLoader();
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        //holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
        Log.d("TEST","Printing Names onBindView Holder"+mDataset.get(position).getName());
        holder.nameText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
        holder.phoneText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.image.setImageUrl(mDataset.get(position).getImage(),mImageLoader);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

and my Fragment is

```html
public class english extends Fragment implements Response.Listener , Response.ErrorListener {

    View view;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Context context;
    private List<Model> contactList  = new ArrayList<>();
    private String url ="https://api.androidhive.info/json/contacts.json";
    Button btn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,container,false);
        context = getContext();
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,2);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        getContactList();
        return view;
    }

    private void getContactList(){
        Log.d("TEST","Getting Contact list");
        Controller.getInstance(context).makeNetworkCalls(Request.Method.GET,url,this,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Object response) {
        Log.d("TEST","Got The response" +response);
        if (response == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't fetch the contacts! Pleas try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        List<Model> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Model>>(){}.getType());
        contactList.addAll(items);
        MyAdapter rcAdapter = new MyAdapter(contactList,context);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: did u satted adapter for the recyclerview please see your fragment code

Comment: whats in mDataSet

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki this is the tutorial I am following http://kukroid.com/2017/12/13/recyclerview-with-cardview-in-a-gridlayout/   since for now when clicked on item..it shows toast message of position of each item..but I was looking forward to modify the code and launch new and different activity for each item based on position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its Simple

First Create URL Array 
in The Adapter Classs

```
ArrayList<String> UrlsToTran=new ArrayList<>();
```

in The Adapter Class Constructor

```
MyAdapter(Context mContext)
{
  //Assing Context 
  //Assign The Urls
    UrlsToTran.add("www.stackoverflow.com");
    UrlsToTran.add("www.facebook.com");
    //And Add More Values As U need

}
```

Then Add OnClick Listener

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    //holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    Log.d("TEST","Printing Names onBindView 
     Holder"+mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.nameText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.phoneText.setText(mDataset.get(position).getPhone());
    holder.image.setImageUrl(mDataset.get(position).getImage(),mImageLoader);

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
{
     context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(UrlsToTran.get(position).toString())));

}
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashvin for your help...but How do I create Array...I am looking to open different url for each item when clicked will open new url in browser as I have stated above..but I got your point somehow but I'm blank on how to create Arraylist that contains multiple url?

Comment: I'm getting multiple errors I ...first it says context cannot be resolved and then variable position accessed from inner position and when I pasted the above code containing urlsTran it say no default constructor availaible.

Comment: please see How to use Recycler View Demos on YouTube and Other And Accept My Answer if helped

Comment: @Asvin I followed your example and now when I click any item ..I'm getting this error     Process: com.nepalpolice.pustakalaya, PID: 23886
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.nepalpolice.pustakalaya.online.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:149)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

Comment: are u use u added values to url @BirNepali

Comment: I don't know I pasted your solution and compiled the app and it compiled sucessfully but when I ran it gave me  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0  error...

Comment: then add 18 items in urlToTra obj

Comment: u have teamViewer

Comment: yes I have ..I'll post  usernmae and id just give me a sec

Comment: My id is 559 646 901 and password is  11mu6n

Comment: thank u for connecting with me now your error solve @BirNepali

Comment: Totally Totally appreciated it..Thanks for such kindness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178900/discussion-between-bir-nepali-and-ashvin-solanki).

Comment: Hello @Ashvin , I need small help..won't take too much...!! please if you have free time.

Comment: Thank for response.I solve it after 2 hours of head banging..!! I have send you message in chat room for some information as I want to start learning from scratch and I'm  looking forward to build app which I have sent you emai..and need guidance and help of  yours of where should I start or what should I learn if I need to build same app...please have a look..!! Thanks once again.

Comment: I have move the discussion to chat where I have sent you message..anyway could you please mail me on searchbbc1881@gmail.com. I'll send you the same query...will be wonderful if i get the good guidance and I'll start from today onwards.

Comment: sended chat invitation please check gmail @BirNepali

Comment: okay I'll have a look....!! could you please check below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070206/how-to-put-imageview-over-relativelayout

Comment: I need some help with, Here is the Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107266/retrive-image-from-firebase-to-show-in-my-imageview

Answer (score 0):

First, for every item in your adapter create an OnClickListener like this:

```
    holder.image.setOnClickListener(v->{

    });
```

Now Create an interface between the adapter and the fragment/activity that shows the list

```
 public interface ModelListener {
        void onModelClicked(Model model);
}
```

In your activity/fragment listen to an item click and send the intent

```
new ModelListener(){

   public void onModelClicked(Model model){
       startActivity(new Intent(.., model.getUrl()));
   }
}
```

Comment: It is too complex for me..I was looking for something that for position 0 it will launch intent one for position 1 it will launch separate intent and so on..can't it be done?

Comment: It's not that complex, think about that you will have to maintain 2 different lists with your solution

Comment: Here is the tutorial I am following http://kukroid.com/2017/12/13/recyclerview-with-cardview-in-a-gridlayout/. It returns item position for now....and I would like to launch different url in web browser for each item click..as stated above...could you please have a look at above link and kindly help me with your solution mentioned above?