# Retrieve Image from Firebase to show in my Image view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm looking forward to display the images stored in Firebase Storage with reference from Firebase Database.

Below is my Firebase Data Structure

[image]

and my Storage Structure is

[image]

Below is my code of recycle adapter that I'm using to retrieve images from Firebase

```
public class SubjectBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectBooksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Books> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    Books b;

    public SubjectBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView bookName,bookAuthor,bookDesc,bookPrice,bookCall;
        ImageView iv;

        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view);

            iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dbreference = database.getReference("books");
            bookName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
            bookAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
            bookDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookDesc);
            bookPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookPrice);
            bookCall = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookCall);
            fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("books");

        b = bookslist.get(position);
        holder.bookName.setText(b.getBname());
        holder.bookAuthor.setText(b.getBauthor());
        holder.bookDesc.setText(b.getBdesc());
        holder.bookPrice.setText("Rs. "+b.getPrice());
        holder.bookCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Log.e("Current user is ", fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                b = bookslist.get(position);
                String[] arr = {b.getSelleremail(),b.getSellername(),b.getBname(),b.getBauthor()};
                //Log.e("Seller is ",b.getSellername());
                Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(),Chat.class);
                in.putExtra("seller",arr);
                v.getContext().startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        Glide.with(cv.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(b.getPics())).placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.bshelf).into(holder.iv);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

But it shows every other details but doesn't show the image...Here is the screenshot

[image]

It thus shows the default bshelf.png from drawable folder.

Comment: problem is with your upload method you are not getting url from it see you are storing wrong url for image.

Comment: BUt I'm getting other details like Book name, Description , Total Amount...only I'm not getting is image.

Comment: for uploading image to storage method is different. first you have to upload image then its on complete method you will get url and then you will save that url in your model class and will upload it to database

Comment: So what can i do then..I have also shared the project above??

Comment: @BirNepali store image url in ur fierbase database

Comment: Umm  Okay I'll try but since I"m learning from the code shared on github and by correcting the error and mistakes....I'm not sure if I can solve it or not..!! App is almost finished ..everything works fine..just if this could be done then job would be finished.

Comment: Important thing is that image is not separate here.it should be on list of Books as there will more then 400/500 books so..separate image of books with unique name , it's description is required to show users.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your pic with a download url from your firebase storage. When saving an image, you should get the download url of an image from firebase storage.

**EDIT:**

In your onActivityResult()

```
private byte[] imageByte;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        iv1.setImageURI(filePath);
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            iv1.setImageURI(resultUri);
            imageByte = uriToByteArray(resultUri);

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}

public byte[] uriToByteArray(Uri uri) {
InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

     ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ((len = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

and in class t2 extends AsyncTask:

```
        @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... bookid) {
        if(filePath != null) {
            storageRef =  mStorageRef.child(bookid[0]);
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putBytes(imageByte);

    uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        String download_url = task1.getResult().toString();
                  }
            });


             }
         });
}
```

And when you want to show the image:

```
Books b = list.get(position);
Glide.load(b.getPics);
```

I didn't test it but i think that's a better approach when saving an image to firebase. Hope it helps

Comment: , Thank you for kind response...can you please give me some more  details

Comment: If I'm not wrong that is not the right link if you wanna show an image from firebase storage, it should be the download link of an image. May I see your code on how you save the image? I can help you with that

Comment: Ok @Aj Do you have a Teamviewer..I'll share id and password..and you can have a look at my whole project...it'll save us time and I think is better approach if you are okay with that

Comment: Here is my ID 559 646 901  and password: bi153s

Comment: Here is the code..can you  please kindly have a look into it https://github.com/BlueYeti1881/Pustak

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: Okay ..I"m constantly refreshing my browser for your response..please take your time...!!! I'll  be waiting.

Comment: Hey I changed something. Please check. I change `storageReference.addOnSuccess` to `storageReference.addOnComplete`

Comment: Its on UploadBook.java

Comment: Only addonSuccess, I was able to find in UploadBook.java which is  
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... bookid) {
            if(filePath != null) {
                mStorageRef.child(bookid[0]).putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                   
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl(); could you please check where you added.

Comment: Copy the codes above. I updated it or you may check github. I propose a file change

Comment: nope it didn't work.throws multiple errors....I'd be happy to share my pc via Teamviewer if you can have look at my code.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm sorry I don't have teamViewer

Comment: It's okay..I'm also searching for solution on various blog ..Hope someone comes with better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ShowImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//recyclerview object
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//adapter object
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//database reference
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//list to hold all the uploaded images
private List<Upload> uploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    uploads = new ArrayList<>();

    //displaying progress dialog while fetching images
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //dismissing the progress dialog 
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //iterating through all the values in database
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploads.add(upload);
            }
            //creating adapter
            adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), uploads);

            //adding adapter to recyclerview
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Please open this link it is very useful to you:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-example/